# How to loop .sh script file names to .txt?

Tags: linux, loops, sh, ls

Apologies, I am new to the linux environment. I am attempting to create a .sh file that puts files depending on their file name into a .txt with the file names  corressponding to the day of the year. Rather than having the .sh file have 365 lines for each day of the year is there a way to loop through in daily increments?

currently I am using

```
ls A2018001* > A2018001.txt
ls A2018002* > A2018002.txt
ls A2018003* > A2018003.txt
ls A2018004* > A2018004.txt
```

etc..

Which is okay but is there a way to avoid having 365 lines of code in the .sh with a loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way:

```
for i in {2018001..2018365}
do
  ls A${i}* > A${i}.txt 
done
```

Generate the loop for 1 to 365 and then list the files and redirect.

Comment: This returns ```ls: cannot access 'A{2018001..2018365}*': No such file or directory```. I am probably making a simple mistake due to unfamiliarity with linux..

Comment: No, the problem is that you are using a shell other than the shell for which `{..}` notation has special behavior.  (bash)

Comment: Or brace expansion is disabled.

Comment: A further related question, how would I alter this solution so that instead of a .txt with just one days worth of file names i.e ```A2018001*``` so that it would cycle in mulitples of three i.e. ```A2018001*, A2018002*, A2018003*```  all into one .txt? I tried  ```{2018001..2018365..3}```  and this did not find the files..  Thanks again for your help!